# SQL XML PATH--HOW to remove the space in the middle

Tags: sql-server

For the table:

[image: table]

I wanted to get the output like this:

```
1 ab
2 xyz
```

I use the query(SQL Server 2012):

```
SELECT ID, Name = STUFF((SELECT ' ' + Name
                     FROM [dbo].[a] AS a2
                     WHERE a2.ID = a.ID
                     ORDER BY ID
                     FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
                  FROM [dbo].[a] AS a
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID;
```

I got the result:

[image: my result]

How to remove the blank space in the middle?

Comment: Just remove ' ' from select, and change stuff(...,1,1,'') on cast(... as nvarchar(100))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
   SELECT ID, Name =  REPLACE((STUFF((SELECT ' ' + Name
                         FROM [dbo].[a] AS a2
                         WHERE a2.ID = a.ID
                         ORDER BY ID
                         FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')), ' ', '')
                      FROM [dbo].[a] AS a
group by id
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't add a space in your XML query you will not get spaces in the middle. You can simple add empty string so that you don't get an XML back.

```
SELECT ID, Name = (SELECT ''+Name --Use empty string instead of space here
                     FROM [dbo].[a] AS a2
                     WHERE a2.ID = a.ID
                     ORDER BY ID
                     FOR XML PATH(''))
FROM [dbo].[a] AS a
GROUP BY ID ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: This will not work as it truncates the first character of the second column.The result looks as follows   1 b
2 yz

Comment: Vamsi I removed STUFF if you look at my query since we are not adding anyting. I should work please try it on your table.

Comment: @Ann this should be an accepted answer. In other answers: add space, than remove it with replace. Why? Get rid of stuff, get rid of space.

Comment: @gofr1 Thanks for your explanation:)

Comment: @ Biz. Nigatu you are right i was trying with stuff and nospace.      Upvoted your answer